# Rust: Inverting a pattern for str::trim_start_matches

Tags: rust

I want to get rid of everything that's not alphabetic from the beginning of a string. Is there some predefined way to get the effect of this?

```
s.trim_start_matches(!char::is_alphabetic);
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass a closure to [trim_start_matches](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.trim_start_matches) to "remove" the unwanted chars:

```
let trimmed = s.trim_start_matches(|c: char| !c.is_alphabetic());
```